# Android Alert Dialog not displaying the ICON

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The below AlertDialog is not displaying the ICON. I tried the option given in this stackoverflow link.

[Alert dialog is not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903746/alert-dialog-is-not-displaying)

I tried the below option:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(TriviaActivity.this);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Buildeer(getApplicationContext()![enter image description here][1]);
```

Please let me know why the ICON is not displaying.

```
public void callfacebook()
{
    if ( score > 100 )
    {   mpc.start();    }
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(TriviaActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.right);
    alertDialog.setMessage("\t Your Score is : " + score + " \n\n Please share this in Facebook");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(TriviaActivity.this,facebookcall.class);
           activityIntent.putExtra("messageval","score");
           activityIntent.putExtra("level","level5");
           startActivity(activityIntent);
        }                   
        });
    alertDialog.show();
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of you not set title of alert dialog once you have setTitle("Title Text") than alert icon will be display

Answer (score 2):

```
 alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm");
```

You must set title.